# Android ListView Search Adapter Issues

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a problem implementing the search feature for a ListView.

Basically, I get data from a remote server then put it in a list. I think it maybe related to the ArrayAdapter because a list item is supposed to have an id and name rather than just one parameter.

Here are the relevant files involved:
ItemListActivity.java

```
public class ItemListActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;
List<String> items_search = new ArrayList<String>();

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_items = "http://199.0.0.103/pawnshop_2/index.php/android/get_item_list";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
private static final String TAG_IID = "i_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray items = null;

//int cid;  

TextView tvNoItems,tvDebug;
EditText etSearchItem;
//ListView searched;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    tvNoItems = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoItems);
    etSearchItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchItem);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    tvDebug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDebug);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    // Hashmap for ListView
    itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.)
    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllItems().execute();

    // Get listview
    //lv = getListView();
    //final int i=0;

    String products[] = {"Diamond And Emerald Necklace","Diamond Drop Earrings","New Item","Pokemon X","Pokemon Y","Heliptile"};

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_item_detail, R.id.name, products);

    // updating listview
    //setListAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // on selecting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    /*
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String i_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleItemActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_IID, i_id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });*/

    etSearchItem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
           ItemListActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

           String items= "";
           for(int i=0; i<items_search.size();i++){
               items+=" "+items_search.get(i);
           }
           tvDebug.setText("Search: "+ items);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int success = 0;
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ItemListActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading items. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c_id",cid+""));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_items, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Items: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // transactions found
                // Getting Array of Products
                items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String i_id = c.getString(TAG_IID);
                    String name= c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    items_search.add(name);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_IID, i_id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    itemList.add(map);
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (success==0){
            tvNoItems.setText("No items found.");
        }

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ItemListActivity.this, itemList,
                        R.layout.activity_item_detail, new String[] { TAG_IID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.i_id, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: offtopic: hehe code from androidhive hahaha, there is no need to call runOnUiThread from onPostExecute ... this tutorial is so weak ... back on topic: ArrayAdapter can be used with class with id and name as fields/properties ...

Comment: Really? Do I need to create a new adapter class to make it work? Also, can you recommend good sites for implementing the search feature. It's just  my first time to make an android app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good example for custom adapter

[Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

This is example for search data.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234598/custom-filtering-for-custom-arrayadapter-in-listview)